# Setting a value to already be in a text input/textarea

Tags: jquery

Firstly, I'm using a jQuery plugin called inlineFieldLabel to put labels inside my textareas/text inputs.

I have a multi-part form. The idea is to fill the fields in the first part of the form if you decide to go back.

Now, it seems like I can either disable my jQuery plugin if any fields have been previously filled, or I can somehow work around this.

I tried putting something between `<textarea>` and `</textarea>`, as well as putting a `value` attribute into my text input, but it seems that the plugin is blocking that from working.

Is there a way I can simply insert text into the text fields, using jQuery perhaps, in the same manner as a keyboard input (which would cause the plugin to function correctly)?

Comment: Do you want it to store data to be used later. Like if the browser crashes and the data is saved automatically? Probably you're looking for [LocalStorage](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/quick-tip-learning-about-html5-local-storage/)

Answer (score 3):

If you mean have some default text then it's pure HTML:

```
<input type="text" value="hello I'm default value" />
<textarea>hello I'm default value</textarea>
```

For input field of type `text` you need to assign the `value` attribute and for `textarea` element just have the value between the tags.

If you mean via jQuery then for both element types you can have:

```
$("#myInput").val("I come in peace from jQuery");
```

Where `myInput` is the ID of the desired element.

Comment: Thank you. How would I be able to remove a CSS class as well in jQuery?

Comment: @Sennheiser: Don't hijack questions (even your own) for spin-off questions. And look at `.removeClass` (duh). jQuery has some great documentation: use it.

Answer (score 0):

You could simulate keypress as this links explains:

[Is it possible to simulate key press events programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596481/simulate-javascript-key-events)

Hope this helps. Cheers